# Add mime type to HTML link

Tags: html, hyperlink, stream, mime, href

I know how to change the MIME type in a webserver. I used this to make sure the browser downloads my .scrpt file instead of opening the plain text version. So far so good but is it possible to do the same with a link? I would like to link to a file on GitHub but this will open as a plain text file. Can I add a "MIME type attribute" to the link to tell the browser to download the file?

This is what I would like to see:

```
<a mimetype="application/octet-stream" href="http://gist.github.com/raw/279094/39d5a2c1037288d5ee0ba1a17dca9edb368bbe42/RepairiPhotoDates.scpt">download</a>
```

Comment: The MIME type does not determine whether a file is viewed or downloaded. It's the browser that decides this, based on the MIME type and the Content-Disposition header.

Comment: I have the same problem: The MIME-type for the files I want to serve is not set up by my hosting company, and there is no way to change that. Is there really no way to tell the browser in the <a...> link what it's going to download?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Time to answer my own question. This is a really old question and it probably wasn't possible at the time but lots has changed since then. The HTML5 spec added the `download` attribute:

```
<a href="hugepdf.pdf" download>Download file</a>
```

This will do exactly what I need, tell the browser to download the file instead of opening it. Thanks to [Jonathan Svärdén](http://svarden.se/blog/2013-04-22-right-click-and-save-as/) for solving my years old question!

Comment: @Cimm Can you tell how to change the MIME type in the web server

Comment: @muthu That depends on the webserver. I suggest you Google "<name of webserver> MIME type" and ask another question on SO if that doesn't solve your question. This is not really the place to ask this question.

Comment: Note: this solution is not great for everyone because of the support for the download attribute. You can check it here http://caniuse.com/#search=download

Comment: in Edge, and therefore probably Chrome, you can provide the intended download's file name, with or without extension, to the download attribute like `<a href="hugepdf.pdf" download="huge-pdf-by-cimm">Download file</a>`. This will download the file as that name.

Answer (score 16):

You can specify a [type attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-type-A), but the content-type sent by the server is authoritative.

> This attribute gives an advisory hint as to the content type of the content available at the link target address. It allows user agents to opt to use a fallback mechanism rather than fetch the content if they are advised that they will get content in a content type they do not support.

Other than that, no, you can't.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. As you explained... Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set up a middleman script which downloads the file in question to the server, then uploads it to the user with a different MIME type?

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not concerned about the HTTP response headers. This is absolutely a server-side problem, which has to be solved in the HTTP repsonse headers before the HTTP reponse body(/content?) is sent. Without a scripting language like Ruby or PHP there is nothing you can do.

Comment: It is not a server side problem, some severs (rest APIs) van deliver several mime-types from one endpoint. So you would need to solve that on the front end.