# remote css from local file doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I'm a total noob to CSS.

I have a css file both locally and remotely. I load a local html file (that is, c:\temp\index.html) in the address bar. I use firefox.

The file sets the height of 'html', 'body' and 2 divs to 100% (height: 100%)

When I link to the local css file, everything works ok. When I link to the remote file, it looks like the height style (at least) doesn't work. I see this when trying to get the offsetHeight property of the body element in javascript.

What can be the reason for this?

I link to the remote site using: 
    `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="https://raw.github.com/SirPepe/Pik5/master/assets/css/pik5.css">`

(the doctype of the local file is html)

To test: clone https://github.com/SirPepe/Pik5, load the local index.html file. then change it so `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="assets/css/pik5.css">` becomes `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="https://raw.github.com/SirPepe/Pik5/master/assets/css/pik5.css">`. Reload to see the slides are no longer properly setup

NOTE: using firebug I see the css file loads

Comment: Please show how you link to remote css

Comment: By "locally" you mean something like `http://localhost/file.html` or just double clicking the HTML file from Windows Explorer?

Comment: Needs more info and code

Comment: updated with more information

Comment: this is interesting.... one of the things i noticed is that when the github file is used, line 5 is ignored... but a diff shows no differences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after doing some digging, it looks as though your CSS file is being *linked* to, but none of your styles are actually applied. That led me to believe that there was something else going on. I ran your html through a validator and found nothing specific, but when running your github css through a validator, I got this response:

**I/O Error: Unknown mime type : text/plain**

It looks like github sends a Content-Type HTTP header that says text/plain instead of text/css for your style sheet file. You may be able to simply define `type="text/css` in your html document for that stylesheet link, but otherwise I'm unsure of how you can solve this issue since you don't have access to their mime-type settings.

See a similar issue here: [Add mime type to HTML link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110269/add-mime-type-to-html-link)

Answer (score 2):

Dave's post indeed describes the problem.  Here's the solution.  You need to use `http://rawgithub.com` instead of `http://raw.github.com`.  Yup, that's right, just drop the `.`!

The problem is that Github doesn't serve its "raw" files with the right MIME type to allow you to hot link them.  Enter Ryan Grove, who created the [rawgithub.com](http://rawgithub.com) site to solve this problem.  When you hit its server requesting a file, it will in turn get that file from Github's servers, and correct the MIME type for you.

Warning: it is NOT for production use.  Use only for demos and development.