# xpages how to open/save a file from a link

Tags: xpages

Is there any chance I can open or save an existing file after clicking a link from an xpage?

My scenario: A link to an attachment ( an excel file ) so all users when clicking the link, they will have the possibility to open or save the file.

My app works both on Lotus Client and web.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I edited my question, to make it more clearly.

Comment: I've also looked at http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM, but I don't know how to modify for my scenario, how to attach the file to a rich text

Comment: When you say open/save do you mean: open, edit and then save back into the same location?

Comment: Just access the file: open it, and if the users can open the file, they can save it of course from the file properties. In the clasic Notes, I create this in the following way: from the outline, one outline entry redirect you to  a page which contains this file as an Attachment on the page. Then the users can open it with 'double-click'.

Comment: So which part of my article was not clear. It describes how to create a link to an attachment. When you click on such a link the file gets processed by the browser and depending on the configuration automatically opens or is offered for save/download. What did not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume (from your comments) that you are looking for a way to store one certain Excel file somewhere and to give users access to this file with a link.

You can achieve that this way:

1. Store your Excel file in your database at `Resources / Files` (e.g. as "sample.xls")
2. Create a link in your XPage pointing to this file just with the name (e.g.  "sample.xls")

   `<xp:link escape="true" value="sample.xls">Excel sample file</xp:link>`

Users can open or download this file in browser or XPiNC clicking on link.

Comment: Initially, it didn't work because of the file name: I had spaces inside the name... Now I changed its name, and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper content type. For an existing file you would need to make your own service (XAgent) to alter it. Or you can try to [set it for the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110269/add-mime-type-to-html-link).
And bear in mind, that action associated to content type is configured in browser - so every user has it's own.

Comment: Could you give me a code example for altering the file via an XAgent? Also, the file must be imported to the .nsf as a resource?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make the file available normally, Knut's answer is about what you want: store the file as a File Resource in the database and link to it on the XPage. I would add one adjustment, though: start the URL in the "value" property with a "/", e.g.

```
<xp:link value="/sample.xls" text="Excel sample file"/>
```

The reason for this is to ensure that the generated link is always relative to the NSF, not the XPage - without it, you'd have a problem if you open the XPage with a link like "/someView/someDocKey" (with display-XPage-instead in the form) or if you happen to include extra path info after the XPage (e.g. "/foo.nsf/somePage.xsp/some/path/info").

But if you mean that you want to cause the browser to display the Save File dialog instead of whatever its normal behavior would be (e.g. IE opening the Excel file in the window), the core of the solution is the Content-Disposition header. If this header is set to tell the browser the file is an "attachment", then the browser will prompt the user (or do whatever its normal file-download routine is) instead of opening inline.

Depending on how the file is stored, the solution will either be fairly easy or not-impossible-but-sort-of-a-pain:

1. If it's a file attached to a document, I believe that the normal  control generates links to an attachment-download service that adds this header normally.
2. If it's not (e.g. it's a file resource), then Frantisek's advice comes into play: you'd have to write your own shim XAgent or servlet that writes this header and then spits out the file's contents.

While the latter is doable, it's a pain, and so I'd suggest trying to wrangle your attachment into a normal document if at all possible. For example, if it's attached to a document in a hidden view, you could do something like:

```
<xp:panel>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="attachmentDoc" action="openDocument" ignoreRequestParams="true">
            <xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[${javascript:
                database.getView("SomeLookupView").getFirstEntry().getUniversalID()
            }]]></xp:this.documentId>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:fileDownload value="#{attachmentDoc.Body}"/>
</xp:panel>
```