# Making a webpage automatically initiate an audio file download

Tags: html, download, meta-tags, redirect

I am trying to create a page on my site such that when a user lands on the page a audio file download is initiated.

I attempted putting the following code in between my header tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=MyAudioFile.mp3">
```

However, this doesn't start an automatic download after 1 second, rather it simply redirects the user to 
www.mywebsite.com/MyAudioFile.mp3. Essentially, this will result in the audio being streamed as opposed to being downloaded.

How can I modify this code to make the mp3 file automatically download as opposed to having it streamed?

Note: the reason why this is being done is because there is an email that goes out with a "download audio file" button. I want the URL of that button to point to this page that will automatically download the audio file without the user having to click on another download button.

Answer (score 1):

The web-server can be configured to handle *.mp3 files as a MIME type that will be downloaded.

Instead of `audio/mpeg` the MIME-type can be set to `application/octet-stream`.

For Apache you can configure this on a per-directory basis using a .htaccess file.

Option 1)

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:mp3)$">
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Option 2)

```
AddType application/octet-stream .mp3
```

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124279/force-mp3-file-to-download-using-http-content-disposition-attachment-in-url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977159/set-content-disposition-header-to-attachment-only-on-files-in-a-certain-director http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401650/stop-mp3-file-from-streaming-in-browsers

Comment: Thanks for the answers - unfortunately I am using weebly and there is no way to access the .htaccess file ..... Would I able to add either of the snippets in the header tags of the HTML document and have it work?

Comment: Seems HTML5 has that ability using the `download` attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16194104/2438830 http://svarden.se/blog/2013-04-22-right-click-and-save-as/